# Knockout.js mapping options being ignored on nested values

Tags: knockout.js, mapping

I am unable to get the knockout.js mapping options to work on nested values. With the following code, the first level "shouldBeCopied" works fine and the nested "shouldBeCopied" value is always an observable.

```
var data = {
    shouldBeCopied: "copied",
    nested: {
        shouldBeCopied : "copied"
    }
};

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
    'copy': ["shouldBeCopied"],
    "nested": {
        'copy': ["shouldBeCopied"]
    }
});

console.log(vm);
```

Any ideas?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAHxJ/2/) if anyone wants to play around with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the the `copy`, `ignore`, `observe`, etc options you don't need to minic the object structure in your mapping options (like when using `create`)

What you need to to is to use a property accessor expression (`"nested.shouldBeCopied"`) in your `copy` array to configure nested properties:

```
var data = {
    shouldBeCopied: "copied",
    nested: {
        shouldBeCopied : "copied"
    }
};

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
    'copy': ["shouldBeCopied","nested.shouldBeCopied"]
});
```

Will output:

[image]

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MKad/).

Comment: Thank you!  My hero!  This functionality really should be put in the docs.

Comment: It is somewhat mentioned in the [documtation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#observing_only_certain_properties_using_observe): look for the "Drilling down into arrays/objects works but copy and observe can conflict:" part. But this feature is not as clearly documentation as it should.