# Use property address with ko mapping Ignore option

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Although it is only mentioned in passing in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#observing_only_certain_properties_using_observe) (search the page for "Drilling") I was under the [impression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553708/knockout-js-mapping-options-being-ignored-on-nested-values) that you can use property addresses to ignore certain properties when performing KO mapping operations. i.e.

```
var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(
  {
    ignoreThis: "This will not be ignored",
    complex: {
      includeThis: "This will be included",
      ignoreThis: "This will be ignored"
    }
  }, {ignore: ["complex.ignoreThis"]);
```

will produce a `mapped` object with the following structure:

```
{
  ignoreThis: "This will not be ignored",
  complex: {
    includeThis: "This will be included",
  }
}
```

This works as expected and the proper observables are copied in. See the mapping section of my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayseeare/3b17r0ys/).

However mapping back does not seem to allow me to do so. For example:

```
var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(
  {
    ignoreThis: "This will not be ignored",
    complex: {
      includeThis: "This will be included",
      ignoreThis: "This will be ignored"
    }
  });

var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(mapped, { ignore: ["complex.ignoreThis"]}
```

Results in an `unmapped` object like this:

```
{
  ignoreThis: "This will not be ignored",
  complex: {
    includeThis: "This will be included",
    ignoreThis: "This will be ignored"
  }
}
```

(See JSON1 in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayseeare/3b17r0ys/))

Using this:

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(mapped, { ignore: ["ignoreThis"]}
```

Results in an undesirable `unmapped` object like this...

```
{
  complex: {
    includeThis: "This will be included",
  }
}
```

(See JSON2 in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayseeare/3b17r0ys/))

No use at all...

What am i doing wrong?